# Windows Server 2008 R2 sees only 2 cores on a quad core?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I recently upgraded my server downstairs from a E8400 to a Q6700.

However, when I go into task manager and every other tool, the computer swears that there are only 2 cores on the machine. In addition to that, the computer runs FREAKING slow.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm at a total loss...

Comment: You could need to do some BIOS upgrade. Have a look at the BIOS changelog. Which board?

Comment: EVGA nForce 780i SLI FTW motherboard

Comment: Run a Linux Live CD and you will see if the additional cores are generally visible.

Comment: Good idea - didn't think of that! I will when I get home tonight

Comment: ` the computer runs FREAKING slow` <-- Sounds more like a disk issue than a CPU issue. An E8400 is pretty damn fast.

Comment: All SMART and misc monitoring tools swear the C: drive is 100% :-/

And the Q6700 is in it now, not the E8400. The E8400 is in my gaming rig at 4GHz ;)

Comment: Sounds more like the BIOS doesn't know the CPU and runs it in some fallback mode. Wondering it started anyway. Why should some disk die when changing a CPU?

Comment: What I don't get is, if it ran the 45nm newer CPU, why can't it play well with the older 65nm quad core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a [BIOS upgrade](http://www.evga.com/support/download/showdlinfo.aspx?id=410&type=N&acctype=BIOS&accversion=SZ17&part_number=132-YW-E178). The changelog for the latest version includes this:

> Improve CPU compatiblity

This will probably solve your issues.

Comment: I just RDP'd in and CPU-Z reports the BIOS are on a VERY old version. Great idea, I'll try when I get home!

Comment: After updating the BIOS, the problem remains..

Comment: Didn't get at first it was a downgrade... Can you switch the CPUs between your both computers (so test the Q6700 in your gaming rig)? What's CPU-Z telling about the Q6700?

Comment: After a BIOS flash and a reset I have all the cores! Thanks a lot! Computer is still slow and buggy though O_o